# Angular/HTML - Full JSON will display but cannot display just single attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

Currently I can display a full JSON array by doing {{ Groups | json }}.

It will display like this on my html page:

```
[ { "Id": 3, **"Name": "Name I"**, "Group_Name": "Group I" } ]
```

Put if I do {{ Groups.Name }} I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]
```

However if I go to display this in a list using *ngFor it works perfect.

```html
<select class="form-control">
<option *ngFor="let Group of Groups">{{ Groups.Name }}</option>
</select>
```

Any idea what is going on? This JSON can only have 1 record. If I do {{ Groups[0].Name }} the data will display but I get the following error back.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (
```

My goal is to just have the word "Name I" display on my HTML page. "Name I" is coming from the Array Groups from the value of "Name".

I do not actually want a list I was just using it as an example of it working.

Comment: It should be Group.Name not Groups.Name

Comment: It could be an asynchronous function when you receive the Json object.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<option *ngFor="let Group of Groups">{{ Groups.Name }}</option>
```

to

```
<option *ngFor="let Group of Groups">{{ Group.Name }}</option>
```

as `Groups` is an array you can't access any property directly on it.  That's why you see `Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`

Moreover here `*ngFor="let Group of Groups"` you're iterating for every object/element in `Groups` array . How this works is, in simple words it takes elements of array one by one and assigns it to `Group`, so you must be accessing properties on it. As I mentioned above

```
 <option *ngFor="let Group of Groups">{{ Group.Name }}</option>
```

Comment: My goal is to just have the word "Name I" display on my HTML page. "Name I" is coming from the Array Groups from the value of "Name".

I do not actually want a list I was just using it as an example of it working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Groups is an array of objects in form of "key": "value" pair.

You should be able to access the value by

```
<span>{{ Groups[0]["Name"] }}</span>
```

or

```
<span>{{ Groups[0].Name }}</span>
```

Comment: This is currently what I am using and the text does display but I still get the error noted above.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (